# mySQL: Sub SELECT statement within UPDATE command

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-update, subquery

I'm trying to update a column in `visitors`. I'm also using a sub select statement for the `SET` part of the update query.

```
UPDATE
    visitors AS v
SET
    v.IsFirstVisit = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visitors AS v2 WHERE ..... LIMIT 1)
```

However, mySQL returns this error message

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'v' for update in FROM clause
```

I have no clue why I can't access the 'v' object within the inner select statement. I also don't want to use multiple statements as this would cause a performance issue.

**Question:** How can I use the 'v' object within the inner select?

Update:
This is the entire query

```
UPDATE
    visitors AS v
SET
    IsFirstVisit = (SELECT Count(*) FROM visitors AS v2 WHERE v2.VisitorId < v.VisitorId AND v2.IP = v.IP AND v2.DateTime > v.DateTime [TODO:SUBTRACT30MINUTES] LIMIT 1)
WHERE
    VisitorId = "991"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you looking for this

```
 UPDATE
    visitors 
 SET
    IsFirstVisit = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visitors  WHERE ..... LIMIT 1)
```

edit:

try this

```
    UPDATE
       visitors
    SET
         IsFirstVisit = (SELECT Count(*) FROM visitors v2 inner join visitors v 
         ON v.VisitorId = v2.VisitorId WHERE v2.IP = v.IP AND v2.DateTime > v.DateTime AND v2.VisitorId < v.VisitorId [TODO:SUBTRACT30MINUTES] LIMIT 1)
    WHERE
    VisitorId = "991"
```

Comment: That would not work since I have to access both visitor objects within the "...." of the WHERE clause.

Comment: I added the whole query to the question.

Comment: In your new solution, the inner select statement does not interact with the outer one, but I think I can just insert the VisitorId from within PHP there. That'll work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `inner join` in `UPDATE` statement won't be a bad idea.

```
UPDATE
    visitors inner join (SELECT COUNT(*) as test FROM visitors v) as v
 SET
    isfistvisit = v.test;
```

Another workaround which Im not a big fan of it.

```
update visitors
   set isfistvisit = (
      select count(*) from (
         select count(*) from visitors
      ) as x
      )
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/393a3)